Chronyの設定について
ネットを検索してみたところ、Chronyは11分ごとにRTCに値を書き込むとの記事を見つけました。
この11分は固定で変更できないのでしょうか？
それとも設定で値を変えることは出来るのでしょうか？

質問のタイトルは「～について」で切らずに内容が伝わるような具体的なものを心がけてください。また、念のため見つけた記事のURLも質問に含まれていた方が親切かと思います。

Linuxでシステム時間にRTCを同期させる機能は、Chronyの機能では無く、Linuxカーネルの"11 minute mode"という機能です。Chronyのrtcsync設定はカーネルの機能を有効にしているだけに過ぎません。機能の名前からして同期タイミングは11分毎なのですが、その時間はLinuxカーネルのソースにハードコードされています。
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.9/kernel/time/ntp.c#L501
#define SYNC_PERIOD_NS (11ULL * 60 * NSEC_PER_SEC)

どうしても変更したいとすれば、上記のSYNC_PERIOD_NSの値を書き替えて、Linuxカーネルをコンパイルし直すしかありません。
任意のタイミングで同期させたいというだけであれば、"11 minute mode"を使用せずに、hwclock --systohcを手動で実行するという方法が現実的です。

ありがとうございました。
